# clear setTimeout function onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box that when a user types will log the search query in real time to a text file. As you can imagine doing this can cause a lot of entries if someone miss-spells a word.

I would like to delay the post request 1 second in between key presses, and if the user starts typing again within that 1 second to clear the timeout, and start again.

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) {

    var logTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        searchQuery = searchBox.val();
        $.post("/submit/search/", { query: searchQuery });
    }, 1000);

    logTimer();
    clearTimeout(logTimer);

});
```

Comment: Look into a throttle or debounce library.... https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce

Comment: FYI Think you messed up variable names: `logTimer` and `emailTimer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) {
    // Use _logTimer to prevent if we crashed somthing that exist before.
    // If previous exist, clear it.
    if (this._logTimer!= null) {
       clearTimeout(this._logTimer);
    }

    // Get the timeout id
    this._logTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        searchQuery = searchBox.val();
        $.post("/submit/search/", { query: searchQuery });
        // remember to clear current timeout here.
        this._logTimer = null;
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

Based on you comments, it can be wrapped into a function that act as an manager, created a sample to demonstrate:

```js
var delayManager = function(cb) {
  var timeout = null;
  
  // Create a function to decide whether to call th cb or not.
  return function(time) {
    time = (time == null) ? -1 : time;
    if (timeout !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }
    
    // If called without time, directly call cb
    if (time < 0) {
      cb();
    } else {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      cb();
        timeout = null;
      }, time);
    }
  };
};

// Create a function controller for it.
var delayFunc = delayManager(function() {
    alert("!!!");
});

$("#delay").click(function() {
    delayFunc(2000);
});

$("#now").click(function() {
    delayFunc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="delay">Delay</div>
<div id="now">Now</div>
```

In more complex condition, the manager would need to accept `thisArg` to make the `execution context` be what user expected, but I think it's enough to demonstrate how  to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to have the option to also send the post request immediately?

Comment: You mean, prevent the request to send again until user afk more than 1 sec?

Comment: I actually plan on increasing the timer from 1 to 5 seconds. So say for instance a user clicks on a search result before that timer expires, I would still like the request to be sent for the page changes.

Comment: So you got a button that will send the request immediately, and clear any onholding request?

Comment: Correct. Could the post request be wrapped in a function that is inside of the setTimeout that can be called?

Comment: @Jrags87 Updated my answer, added what you want, take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82848/discussion-between-jrags87-and-fuyushimoya).

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

In your case, you can do something like

```
searchBox.keyup(function (e) {
  if (this.logTimer != undefined) {
    clearTimeout(logTimer);
  }

  this.logTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      searchQuery = searchBox.val();
      $.post("/submit/search/", { query: searchQuery });
  }, 1000);

  logTimer();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little closure trick to keep the timeout delaying self-contained and controlled using a generated function

```
function waitFromLastInvoke(callback, minwait) {
    var i;
    return function (stop) {
        clearTimeout(i);
        if (!stop)
            i = setTimeout(callback, minwait);
    };
}

var command = waitFromLastInvoke(function () {
        searchQuery = searchBox.val();
        $.post("/submit/search/", { query: searchQuery });
    }, 1e3);

searchBox.keypress(function (e) {
    command();
});
```

This would also let you cancel the whole thing by running `command(true)`